# FoxPro Space() Function

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have this:

```
select keyfld, plrevno, space(2) as AAA, ;
    plandt, plan_enddt ;
    from d:\oct_2018_data\DBFS\plan ;
```

What is the `space(2)` part doing? Is it taking the first 2 characters of the plrevno column?

Comment: My guess: it's outputting `'  '` (two spaces) to visually separate the output.

Comment: You know what it does now from Herb Wolfe's message. You could rewrite that query as: select keyfld, plrevno, cast("" as char(2)) as AAA, plandt, plan_enddt from ('d:\oct_2018_data\DBFS\plan')

Comment: Nice way to make those of us who are still making a good living with FoxPro want to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `space()` function returns a string consisting of `n` spaces, where `n` is the value passed to the function.

In this case, it's creating an empty field, 2 characters in length, in the query.